# JSON data in tableview JAVAFX

Tags: json, javafx, tableview

I have the next String JSONArray and I want add it to TableView to JavaFX.

```
[{"id":"1","desc":"new","port":774},{"id":"2","desc":"old","port":774}]
```

What I can do?

ideas please!!

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://java.net/nonav/projects/datafx/sources/core/content/samples/org/javafxdata/samples/datasources/JsonTableSample.java?rev=188) gives the following example:

```
 final TableView<String[]> tableView = new TableView<String[]>();
 DataSourceReader reader = new FileSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("tweets.json"));
 ObjectDataSourceBuilder builder = ObjectDataSourceBuilder.create()
         .itemClass(JsonTableSample.Tweet.class).dataSourceReader(reader)
         .columns("author","text")
         .itemTag("results").format(Format.JSON);
 ObjectDataSource ds = builder.build();
 ds.retrieve();
 tableView.setItems(ds.getData());
 tableView.getColumns().addAll(ds.getColumns());
```

You should probably look there. The full example has a class representing the JSON (JsonTableSample.Tweet).

Comment: The example is using DataFX. You can find more information about the DataFX framework here: http://www.javafxdata.org/